# Bootstrap 3 responsiveness max width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have played around with bootstrap 3 and ran into what I think should be an obvious question.

.container class allows responsiveness based on widths however what if at:

- > <= 940px there should be the 100% width responsiveness
- > > 940px it should start using the margin: 0 auto or centered column with margin on both sides.

similar to xero.com they have margined layout on desktops and then it becomes responsive below a certain width

Answer (score 0):

Please `cotainer-fluid` instead of `container` and use `max-width: 940px` or required width.

If you use `container it will be adaptive content within tablet version`

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1600px; /* or 950px */
}
```